# Select statement inside an Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to self-teach myself SQL. I am working on calling a simple select statement from a stored procedure in oracle.

I have created an employee database with 2 tables; employees and department. I want a select statement which returns all employees from a certain department.

This is what I have so far and I can't figure out where I am going wrong

```
create or replace procedure user_empdepart (depart_name varchar(40))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT emp_name FROM employee JOIN department ON department.departmentID = 
employee.departmentID
    WHERE depart_name = 'research';
END;
```

And then I hope to call the above by;

```
exec user_empdepart(research);
```

I am using SQL Developer Oracle

I get the following error message:

> Error(99,50): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DEPARTMENT" when expecting one of the following: , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where connect

Comment: Want to explain to us what is going wrong?

Comment: you can execute the `select` directly from the client (no need for a stored procedure at all)

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What does it say?

Comment: Sorry for not including that information, this is the error message I am getting ---Error(99,50): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DEPARTMENT" when expecting one of the following:     , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where    connect  --- I understand I can execute the select directly from client but trying to understand stored procedures in a very basic setting :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this -

```
create or replace procedure user_empdepart (depart_name varchar(40))
AS
DECLARE dept_name varchar(200);
dept_name := depart_name;
BEGIN
SELECT emp_name FROM employee JOIN department ON department.departmentID = employee.departmentID
WHERE depart_name := dept_name;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle database, SQL statements executed directly in the client (like SQL-Developer or SQLPlus) are treated as plain, ordinary SQL.
But if you are going to use SQL commands in a procedure or a function, Oracle treats them as PL/SQL commands, not SQL.
For simple INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE commands the syntax in PL/SQL is the same as in SQL, however for SELECT the syntax is slightly different: [PL/SQL SELECT INTO Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm)

You must use `SELECT expression-list INTO variables-list/record FROM .....` syntax. 
You cannot use `SELECT expression-list FROM .....`, this generates a syntax error.